# Starting more than 100 Sites gives error

Tags: iis-8, was

Starting more than 100 Sites gives error.

The World Wide Web Publishing Service service depends on the Windows Process Activation Service service which failed to start because of the following error:

> The service has returned a service-specific error code

Starting the 101st Site always leads to an issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: My bad.  Posting for the first time. Let me delete it.

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/p/1151701/1879243.aspx#1879243 - No max, but central logging will save memory. odd that it's @ 100 though. have you checked that specific site config?

Comment: @user3565431 You should be able to flag for the moderators to migrate it...

Comment: Thsi is resolved and can be closed. <webLimits dynamicRegistrationThreshold needs to be increased.  http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/dynamic-site-activation-in-iis85